# How to loop through Text files, read first n rows, and write to a list or dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with around 3,700 text files, and I'm trying to get a better understanding of the contents of each.  Some files are exactly the same, and change only by quarter, and some are different.  I am thinking of looping through each file, opening them one by one, and writing the contents of the first 3 or 4 or 5 rows to a list, so I can better sense of what files have the same schema.  Here is te code that I put together.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os

results = pd.DataFrame([])
filelist = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\*.txt")
number_of_lines = 3
for filename in filelist:
    for i in range(number_of_lines):
        print(filename)  
        namedf = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=0, index_col=0)
        results = results.append(namedf)
```

Here is the full stack trace.

```
        results = results.append(namedf)
C:\Users\ryans\Downloads\FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312001.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-64ec4bc99b05>", line 12, in <module>
    namedf = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=0, index_col=0)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 458, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1196, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2155, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 862, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 918, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 905, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2042, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

How can I make this code work?  Also, is this the best way to proceed, or is there a better way to work with these 3,700 text files?

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: Appending to a df in a loop is grossly inefficient; it will copy the df to new memory on every iteration. You can get pre-allocated memory to do this, instead, if you pass all the dfs in one go. But 13K is a lot

Comment: I just updated my OP with the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no point to read all files if in the worstcase you want to read 5 lines.

   use `nrows=5` option of `pd.read_csv()`
2. The exception you get is because you assume all files are legit csv files. but in your case the failed file

> "Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2"

You should error handling (try and except) those cases and maintain a list of non-valid csv files.

Comment: I think this makes sense!  However, when I tested this on 3 files, I saw one with a field named 'RIADC899' on column O and in the same column, I have two files named 'TOTAL INTEREST INCOME IN FOREIGN OFF'.  There are similar cases of that.  I see, in column P, a field named 'RIADC900' and under that is 'TOT INTEREST EXPENSE IN FOREIGN OFFI'.  Why would it not create new columns for these new column names?

Comment: hard to follow. Please update your question with these examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
results = []
filelist = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\*.txt")
number_of_lines = 3
for filename in filelist:
    print(filename)
    f =open(filename,"w")
    lines = f.readlines()
    results.append(lines[:number_of_lines])
print(results)
```